# How are measurements done exactly on IBM cloud computers?

Tags: measurement, experimental-realization

A quantum cloud server like from IBM typically returns a string of 0's and 1's such as 0010.

How is this measurement done exactly? I realize that the IBM cloud computers are transmon devices based on Josephson junctions but for simplicity let's assume it's the spin of four electrons we are measuring in the z-basis. What kind of a sample magnetic field setup (simply a toy model illustration to get the idea of practical implementation) do I need to pull off this measurement?

Or any other simple physical realization apparatus (that is not simply mathematical) will also be very helpful for me.

The one qubit case is relatively clear but I am not being able to visualize the n-qubit measurement apparatus when measuring 4 electron spins say.

(p.s. My background is in Electrical Engineering/ Applied Math)

(p.p.s There is another question that is related to this question which can be found here: [Link between binary program output and observable eigenvalue](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/link-between-binary-program-output-and-observable-eigenvalue))